# Is my proof of irrationality correct?

Tags: solution-verification, irrational-numbers

There is a lot of proof on this site about different numbers being irrational. This is just a generalized version.

**THE STATEMENT**:-

If $\forall c,k\in\mathbb{N},N\in\mathbb{N}:N\neq c^k$

then $\sqrt[k]{N}$ is irrational.

**MY PROOF**:-

Let $a,b\in\mathbb{Z}:\gcd(a,b)=1$

$\implies \gcd(a^k,b^k)=1$, call it $eq(1)$

Assume $\sqrt[k]{N}=\frac{a}{b}$

$\implies N=\frac{a^k}{b^k}$

$\implies a^k=Nb^k$

$\implies \gcd(a^k,b^k)=\gcd(Nb^k,b^k)=b^k$, call it $eq(2)$

Now, combining $eq(1)$ and $eq(2)$ would give

$b^k=1$

$\implies b=1$

$\implies \sqrt[k]{N}=a$

$\implies non-integer=integer$, which is a Contradiction

Which means our assumption was wrong and $\sqrt[k]{N}$ is irrational.$QED$

**MY QUESTION**:-

Is my proof entirely valid or is there a problem and if there is a problem then what is it?

Comment: Why the $\implies non-integer=integer$? I mean at this point $\sqrt[k]{N}$ could be an integer, but $\sqrt[k]{N}=a \implies N = a^k$, and this contradicts the definition of $N$ - this is more convincing for me.

Comment: @Dávid Laczkó, how can $\sqrt[k]{N}$ be an integer? In the 'If' part of the statement I said that $N$ is not a perfect k-th power, so by definition $\sqrt[k]{N}$ is not an integer.

Comment: You are right. I just didn't use anything that wasn't explicitly there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment you say

> Assume $\sqrt[k]{N}=\frac{a}{b}$

you should already mention that $b=1$ is ruled out, because you have $N\neq c^k$ in the initial conditions. This would let you finish the proof earlier, when you arrive at $b=1$ later, without having to use vague terminology like "non-integer = integer".

Comment: What do you mean by vague terminology? Why is "non-integer=integer" a vague terminology?

Comment: Using an `=` symbol in a sentence is vague and improper. One uses `=` in equations, and its meaning is (usually) that two objects (numbers, sets, etc) are the same (or equivalent in some sense). Readers will intuitively understand that you mean to say that "$x \in \mathbb{N}$ and $x \notin \mathbb{N}$ can't be both true", but that's precisely the way you should write it down, rather than going for the weird-looking "non-integer=integer" thing.

Comment: But again, the point of my answer is that you didn't even need to go there, you can stop the reasoning earlier, because $b \neq 1$ and $b=1$ can't be both true.

Comment: Oh okay. From your comments it seems to me that I can prove this thing lin a way shorter proof but inorder for us to derive that $b=1$, we have to do almost all the steps in the proof and we get $b\neq 1$ for free from the initials, so how can we make the proof shorter?

Comment: I'm not suggesting it can be done "way" shorter, just shorter. At the step I indicated, add a sentence along the lines of "Notice that because of our initial conditions, we have here the requirement that $b \neq 1$", then keep going as you did until you arrive at $\implies b=1$, and claim contradiction right there.

Comment: Now I understand. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The proof is entirely valid. Although you are using the fact that $(a,b) = 1 \implies (a^k,b^k) = 1$. Which of course is easy to prove with prime factorization.

Comment: Yes I did a jump there. I thought that the fact was obvious and it's also intuitive.

Comment: It is, but notice that if you have prime factorization as a tool you can finish in a bunch of different ways once you have $a^k = Nb^k$ ( it is possible to see that $N$ mus be a perfect $k$'th power)

Comment: How is it possible to see that $N$ must be a perfect k'th number from the equation $a^k=Nb^k$?. Please clarify.

Comment: you can write the prime factorization of $a,b$ and $N$ and then notice that all the exponents in the prime factorization of $N$ must be multiples of $k$.

Comment: Ooooooo okay. Now I understand.